# delete Nos from Mysql cell

Tags: mysql

i wanted to replace all numeric and - from my Mysql cell the content is like this.

```
title 

77460------jeffrey-katzenberg/77460---picture-1-
```

in addition i wanted to delete all content before [img]

```
content

14888.jpg----http://xxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg--picture-1.html[img]
```

i was trying with update replace command but it will take lot of time. so if any better way is around it will be helpful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This will replace all occurrences of `number` and `-`:

```
UPDATE <table name>
   SET description = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(description,'9',''),'8',''),'7',''),'6',''),'5',''),'4',''),'3',''),'2',''),'1',''),'0',''),'-','')
```

Check [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15b866/1)